# Passing a geopandas data frame to `folium.Choropleth` (map renders gray)

Tags: geopandas, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to make a Choropleth map from a GeoPandas data frame, rather than from a geojson file containing only geometry plus a `pandas` dataframe containing statistical data. Specifically, I would like to adapt [this example](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Choropleth-maps), merging the shapefiles for US states with another dataset containing their respective unemployment numbers into a single GeoPandas data frame (`merged`), and then rendering it with `folium.Choropleth`.

[image]

The `folium` documentation says that the `geo_data` parameter can be a `geopandas` object. When I pass the `geopandas_data_frame.geometry` to it, the map renders. However, when I pass `merged["Unemployment"]` to the `data` parameter, each state renders in blue, despite the fact that the numbers vary.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=merged,
    name='choropleth',
    data=merged["Unemployment"],
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=1,
    legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

[image: Broken folium.Choropleth map]

I have tried changing the data type of merged["Unemployment"] from `float` to `int` to `str`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815295/folium-chropleth-map-renders-grey-shading-instead-of-true-colors-of-the-thematic).

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Folium uses GeoJSON objects to plot the geometries (the geo_data param). You can use the geopandas but you'll have to convert it in the function call.

```
folium.Choropleth(geo_data=merged.to_json(),
                  name='choropleth',
                  data=merged,
                  columns=["id", "Unemployment"],
                  fill_color='YlGn',
                  fill_opacity=0.7,
                  line_opacity=1,
                  key_on="feature.properties.id",
                  legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)').add_to(m)
```

The key_on parameter is the tricky one, it has to match the structure of the merged.to_json() file, just print it and check.